# How to use "APP_INITIALIZER" into a library with standalone components

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, angular-standalone-components, app-initializer

In my angular **library** (library word is very important here!) I've it :

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          deps: [TreatmentDeclaratorServiceSpecificImpl],
          useFactory() {
            return async () => Promise.resolve();
          },
          multi: true
        },
        TreatmentDeclaratorServiceSpecificImpl
    ]
})
export class TreatmentDeclaratorModule { }
```

The goal is to force Angular to instanciante TreatmentDeclaratorServiceSpecificImpl, also if application not import the service.

How can I do it with an application which use standalone components? Application is forced to declare all theses classes into his bootstrap function??

The APP_INITIALIZER was transparent for application, I wish this was still the case with standalone components.

Its possible?

Regards

Comment: Possible this docs is what you need: https://blog.stackademic.com/how-and-when-to-use-app-initializer-in-standalone-angular-16-application-37b63a56e185

Comment: Thanks but this article has always the same problem : Solution is to declare a thing into bootstrap function of main application. I want that solution not require to do another thing into application than add import of module into @Component({imports: [MyLib]})

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it

```
export const provideTreatment = (): EnvironmentProviders => {
  const providers: (Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[] = [
    TreatmentDeclaratorServiceSpecificImpl,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      deps: [TreatmentDeclaratorServiceSpecificImpl],
      useFactory() {
        return async () => Promise.resolve();
      },
      multi: true
    },
  ];

  return makeEnvironmentProviders(providers);
};
```

And use in AppModule or ApplicationConfig

```
providers: [
  provideTreatment(),
  ...
]
```

Maybe take a look at how [Router](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/provide_router.ts#L90) and [HttpClient](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/http/src/provider.ts#L107) do this.

Comment: +1 This is roughly what I'd do too. OP wants to emulate the `XxxModule.forRoot()` pattern rather than providing an `APP_INITIALIZER` token provider in their module (which could be imported well after the application has finished initializing). (Or just force the issue by including the provider in the `EnvironmentProviders` returned by proving the module as you've done - probably the safer way to do it).